# Web Api 2 Object size

Tags: json, rest, http, debugging, asp.net-web-api2

Ok, here is a strange one.

For testing this issue I have a endpoint like this:

```
 [HttpPut]
    public string Put(object value)
    {
        return value != null ? "ok" : "fail";
    }
```

When throwing data directly at it the value object allways becomes the JSON i throw at it (as expected). However the app I'm developing requires me to go through a gateway that adds security to the call by verifying some headers and so.

When going through the gateway that forwards to my endpoint everything also seems ok until the body of the call hits a certain size(apperantly 471 chars is ok 472 is not) then the value object is *null* (and the therefore the method returns 'fail').

All this led me to believe that the GW truncates the body at a certain size and therefore makes it invalid JSON and the value object becomes *null*. BUT after talking to the provider of the gateway they told me that they tested it and this could not be the issue.

**Here comes the really strange part**

In my further pursuit of the problem I added a BeginRequest listener like this:

```
   context.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
```

I added only one line to the interceptor for debugging purposes (to see if the body got truncated):

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs("c:\\test.txt", true);
```

After adding this line everything works like a charm, all call gets thru (regardless of size) and value is never *null*. I tried removing the line again and we are back to the original issue where it fails at a certain size.

**What on earth is going on**

I really need some advice here on how to proceed debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue in the 3rd party GW anyways. The are now trying to fix the problem.